# Ignoring white spaces

Tags: xml

I am using XCers DOM parser for parsing an XML file . However every time I get a #text node 
every time i try to access the element node . I have set setIncludeIgnorableWhitespace to false  . Still no avail .

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the `normalize-space(text)` Xpath function:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space